# Cognos cut off decimal point

Tags: report, substring, cognos

In my data set there is a field that is currently a character field and I need to convert it to a numeric one. the problem is not only are there '%' signs hard coded in the data but there are decimal points in there as well and places after the decimal points is not consistent. AKA...

```
    42.01%
      8.1%
       22%
      .05%
```

I substringed off the % sign but is there a way to just cut the decimal point off and everything after it so then I can just cast it as an integer?

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Cut % then convert to double. Then apply ceiling function.

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was put leading 0's on the front of the element because cognos was not reading the entries that started with decimal places. then I had to substring the % off and trim and then cast as a number.